# javascript. Нелинейное изменение положения элемента с течением времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть блок, при нажатии он начинает двигаться: сначала прямо, а потом должен спускаться вниз по дуге. Я не понимаю, как сделать этот круговой спуск вниз. У меня получается, что координаты элемента меняются не по синусоиде, а просто линейно.

Пример кода ниже.

Вопросы:

1. Как записать это все в одну анимацию?
2. Как исправить задержки в тех местах, где не стоит delay?
3. Как сделать нелинейное изменение положения элемента по осям Х и У?

```js
$('.ring').click(function() {

  $(this).delay(1500).animate({
      left: 200,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(1500).animate({
      left: 400,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').delay(1500).animate({
      left: 500,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').animate({
      left: 580,
      top: 105,
    },
    800);
  $('.ring').animate({
      left: 500,
      top: 185,
    },
    500);
  $('.ring').animate({
      left: 400,
    },
    500);

});
```

```css
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ring">
</div>
```

Comment: тут тупо математические формулы применять надо. [Примерчик](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxVxrW)

Comment: знал бы я как ее встроить нашел вот эту: function circ(timeFraction) {
  return 1 - Math.sin(Math.acos(timeFraction))
} - подходит но как встроить не знаю

Comment: используйте `options.step` в этом варианте `jQuery.animate` - http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Comment: функция function circ возвращает одно значения, для движения вам необходимо два значения.

Comment: да мне бы понять как это все работать должно

Comment: хотя бы подскажите как все в одну анимацию записать, Или пример где этот самый step используется для паузы, а я уже к своему привяжу

Answer (score 1):

Пример нелинейной анимации, для того чтобы двигался объект нелинейно, координаты его должны меняться в соответствии с математическими формулами. В этом примере показано как функция возвращает два значения для перемещения по координате `x` и `y`. Не математик, поэтому формулу для необходимой вам траектории вам придется искать самому.

**Пример 1**

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){
  
    
  
  $('#but').on('click', function(){
  
    
  var  div=$( "div" );
  
  div.css({
   position: "fixed",
  });
  
  div.animate(
    {
      radius: 10000
    },
    {
      duration: 10000,
      step: function( r,fx ){
        $(this).css({
          top:Math.sin(r/500)*150+200,
          left:Math.cos(r/500)*150+200
        })
      }
    }
  );
    
  });
  
  

  
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="but" value="запуск!">
<div>Hello</div>
```

**Пример 2**

```js
$(function(){


  
    $('#but2').on('click', function(){
    
      var  div=$( "div" );
  
  div.css({
   position: "fixed",
   left: "500px"
  });
  
  div.animate(
    {
      left: 0
    },
    {
      duration: 4000,
      step: function( st ){
        $(this).css({
          top:Math.sin(st/50)*50+200
        })
      }
    }
  );
    
    });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="but2" value="запуск 2!">
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: а можно ли сделать чтобы в первом примере он описал дугу?